# How to keep PHP dropdown selection on refresh inside a form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to keep the current selection in the dropdown when you submit the form. How do I do that?

My code:

```
echo '<select name="RoomSelection">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectroom1)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['Location'].'">'.$row['Location'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy:

```
echo '<select name="RoomSelection">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectroom1)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['Location'].'"';
    if($_POST['RoomSelection']==$row['Location']) echo ' SELECTED '; 
    echo '>'.$row['Location'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

You just write  SELECTED if the value is equal to the post value. If your form is in method POST, you must adapt it if it's in GET.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the submitted value (either from POST or GET). Then just add a condition inside the `<option>`. Check if the current iteration value is equal to the selected value:

Basic idea:

```
$selected_value = isset($_POST['RoomSelection']) ? $_POST['RoomSelection'] : '';

echo '<select name="RoomSelection">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectroom1)) {
    $selected_attribute = ($selected_value === $row['Location']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option value="'.$row['Location'].'" $selected_attribute>'.$row['Location'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```